# Assessing the security of Docker in Kubernetes (+Rancher)

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, rancher

I have assessed the security configuration of Docker containers within a Kubernetes cluster using `docker-bench`. I have noted that all Kubernetes containers such as

```
kube-proxy
kubelet
kube-apiserver
k8s_kube-flannel_canal
k8s_POD_canal
k8s_trident-main_trident-csi
...
```

run as **root**. Is this necessary?

Furthermore, some Kubernetes containers, such as `k8s_trident-main_trident`, `kube-proxy` and `kubelet`  ran in privileged mode. I guess this is necessary for Kubernetes to work properly.

My question is: how do you properly assess the security configuration of Docker in Kubernetes? I understand that most settings are covered by Kubernetes, such as CPU/memory usage, PID cgroup limit and health checks. However, now I don't know if I can say anything about the security configuration of Docker when it's managed through Kubernetes and Rancher (RancherOS is also used). Reframing the previous question: what are steps/controls that should be taken to harden Docker in addition to hardening Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

> ...run as root. Is this necessary?

If some of them do, you can assume there should be quite a good reason for that. I believe that creators of **kubernetes** are quite familiar with the concept of **least privilege principle**. So I would say: yes, most probably it is necessary to be able to perform required operations on the node system. However it can be discussed as for example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/57).

Does e.g. **kubeadm** really need root privileges ? Well... to be able to perform all the required operations, yes. Compare with [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/57#issuecomment-262497118) answer.

However ideas about running the whole **kubernetes** cluster as non-root user also arise. I found an interesting [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/AkihiroSuda/rootless-kubernetes) discussing this concept.

You touched really broad topic in your question and it is impossible to provide a single proper answer. I would say it's rather material for an extensive blog article or even e book (compare with [this one](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/kubernetes-security/9781492039075/)).

> Furthermore, some Kubernetes containers, such as
>   `k8s_trident-main_trident`, `kube-proxy` and `kubelet` ran in
>   privileged mode. I guess this is necessary for Kubernetes to work
>   properly.

If you want your containers to be able to perform also certain operations on host system, privileged mode cannot be avoided.

You may also want to familiarize with the following articles in official kubernetes documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/overview/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I've read the documentation you posted. I was more looking for information on the security of Docker in combination with Kubernetes and the overlap it has with functionalities in Kubernetes. For example, when doing a review with docker-bench, some (maybe even most) of the controls are covered by Kubernetes, such as 'ensure the default ulimit is configured appropriately' and 'ensure that the memory usage for containers is limited', but not all (I guess). And I'm really looking for the control that aren't covered by Kubernetes, per se. :)